# Converting polygon to list of coordinates with shapely

Tags: python, polygon, coordinates, geopandas, shapely

I received a code, that expects a list of coordinates such as this as input

```
area_polygon = [{'lat': 46.037286, 'lng': 14.471329},
                {'lat': 46.036733, 'lng': 14.467378},
                {'lat': 46.034822, 'lng': 14.468441}]
```

However, I have input data in form of `shapely.Polygon` and it looks like this:

```
POLYGON ((14.471329 46.037286, 14.467378 46.036733, 14.468441 46.034822))
```

I work with `shapely` and `GeoPandas` libraries and I know how to switch lats and longs. But I don't know how to do everything else to transform a Polygon to the form presented.

Comment: What have you tried? This sort of task is very nearly a pure Python issue, so you might benefit from researching how to generate a list of dictionaries from a list of lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is another solution using the [`mapping()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.mapping):

> returns a new, independent geometry with coordinates copied from the
> context.

```py
import json
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, mapping

poly = Polygon([[14.471329,46.037286],[14.467378,46.036733],[14.468441,46.034822]])

poly_mapped = mapping(poly)

poly_coordinates = poly_mapped['coordinates'][0]

poly_ = [{'lat': coords[1],'lon': coords[0]} for coords in poly_coordinates]

print(json.dumps(poly_))
```

This results in:

```
[{"lat": 46.037286, "lon": 14.471329}, {"lat": 46.036733, "lon": 14.467378}, {"lat": 46.034822, "lon": 14.468441}, {"lat": 46.037286, "lon": 14.471329}]
```

Mind that the above output will contain one point two times, the first and last points, to avoid that use the following piece of code:

```py
poly_ = poly_[:-1]

print(json.dumps(poly_))
```

This results in:

```
[{"lat": 46.037286, "lon": 14.471329}, {"lat": 46.036733, "lon": 14.467378}, {"lat": 46.034822, "lon": 14.468441}]
```

---

**References:**

- [Extract points/coordinates from a polygon in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474549/extract-points-coordinates-from-a-polygon-in-shapely)

Answer (score 11):

Easier with simple list comprehension:

```
poly = Polygon([[14.471329,46.037286],[14.467378,46.036733],[14.468441,46.034822]])
poly.wkt
POLYGON ((14.471329 46.037286, 14.467378 46.036733, 14.468441 46.034822, 14.471329 46.037286)
area_polygon = [{'lat':i[1],'lon':i[0]} for i in list(poly.exterior.coords)]
print(area_polygon)
[{'lat': 46.037286, 'lon': 14.471329}, {'lat': 46.036733, 'lon': 14.467378}, {'lat': 46.034822, 'lon': 14.468441}, {'lat': 46.037286, 'lon': 14.471329}]
```

Comment: The result of `print(poly.wkt)` is the same as `print(poly)`

Comment: It is normal because `print(poly.) = poly.wkt`

Comment: List comprehension is definitely your best friend here: `poly_list  = [[i[1],i[0]] for i in list(poly.exterior.coords)]`, will give you: `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]],...`.

Answer (score 7):

Input data you have is probably a string(?) and it is almost in WKT (Well-known Text) format. Therefore, `shapely.wkt.loads` method helps you. But first, you have to have closed coordinates. That's, the first (lat, long) must also be at the end of the string like:

```
           vvvvvvv                        vvvvvvv
'POLYGON ((1.0 2.0, 10.0 20.0, 20.0 20.0, 1.0 2.0))'
```

The code:

```py
import re
import numpy as np
from shapely import wkt

def add_closing_coordinates(d):
    """ Adds the first 'lat long' to the end"""
    i = re.search(r"\d", d).start()
    j = re.search(r'(\d)[^\d]*$', d).start() + 1
    c = d.index(',')    
    return d[:j] + ", " + d[i:c] + d[j:]

data = 'POLYGON ((1.0 2.0, 10.0 20.0, 20.0 20.0))'
data_wkt = add_closing_coordinates(data)
print(f"data_wkt: {data_wkt}")
# OUT:                                               vvvvvvv
# data_wkt: POLYGON ((1.0 2.0, 10.0 20.0, 20.0 20.0, 1.0 2.0))

polygon = wkt.loads(data_wkt)
coords = np.dstack(polygon.boundary.xy).tolist()[0][:-1]
print(f"coords: {coords}")
# OUT:
# coords: [[1.0, 2.0], [10.0, 20.0], [20.0, 20.0]]


expected_list_of_coordinates_for_received_code = [{"lat": x, "lng": y} for x, y in coords]
print(expected_list_of_coordinates_for_received_code )
# OUT:
# [{'lat': 1.0,  'lng': 2.0},
#  {'lat': 10.0, 'lng': 20.0},
#  {'lat': 20.0, 'lng': 20.0}]
```